# Dirvish - rsync daemon mode - port

Tags: backup, rsync

I am trying to make a dirvish config with unique rsync port.

From the dirvish summary log:

This is what the rsync try to do:

```
rsync -vrltH --delete -D --numeric-ids -pgo --stats --exclude-from=/work/dirvish/host/2019-08-23/exclude host::backup/ /work/dirvish/host/2019-08-23/tree
```

This is what should look like:

```
rsync -vrltH --delete -D --numeric-ids -pgo --stats --port=8730 --exclude-from=/work/dirvish/host/2019-08-23/exclude host::backup/ /work/dirvish/host/2019-08-23/tree
```

This is my dirvish config:

```
client: host
rsync-option: --port 8730
tree: :backup

xdev: 0
index: gzip
log: gzip
image-default: %Y-%m-%d

exclude:
    + /www
    - /vmail
```

This config above makes the rsync wants to run this:

```
rsync -vrltH --delete -pgo --stats --numeric-ids -D rsync-option: --port 8730 --exclude-from=/work/dirvish/host/2019-08-23/exclude host::backup/ /work/dirvish/host/2019-08-23/tree
```

As you can see the command is wrong, the `rsync-option:` appeared in the command.

Does anyone knows how should I use the rsync-option in the config? If I write only --port 8730 in the config it does not added to the rsync command.

Answer (score 1):

After 3 hours wipe the problem has been solved. In the config file you have to add options like this:

```
rsync-option:
        --port
        8730
```

Not in one line, in one line it will cause error. What a .....